# while sudo apt-get -f install i got following error how to fix it

Tags: package-management, software-installation

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-4.8-base_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
(--unpack):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-4.8-base_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you were trying to install a 64 bit package into a 32 bit operating system and it choked.  How about you tell me what you are trying to install and I will tell you the easy way to do it?

studying your post some more.  GCC seems to stand for gnu compiler collection.  From what I can tell that's already installed in ubuntu, so it seems you were trying to install something you should have already had.

Comment: I should add that I only believe GCC is already included.  It is installed on mine, 12.04, and I don't recall installing it, but it might have been part of a larger package.  There is an easy and painless way to find out if it is installed and install it if it is not.  Press the windows key, type soft followed by the enter key.  type GCC.  If you see GCC is not installed, then install it, and if you see that it is already installed, then exit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /boot directory...it might be full

`$> df -H`

if full follow this guide:
[How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error message reads that your machine is `i386` architecture and you are trying to install the package for `amd64` architecture. For solving this open a terminal and do the following:

1) **Clean the apt-cache** :
`sudo apt-get clean`
(since you are having wrong file in cache remove it by this)

2)**Check your package is already installed**(not needed, just to get know) : `gcc`

If not installed you will get the following output

```
$ gcc
The program 'gcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

3)**Install your package** :
`sudo apt-get install gcc`

Now the output will look like the following

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
[sudo] password for adwaita: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    g++-4.8 gfxboot gfxboot-dev libfribidi-bin libstdc++-4.8-dev mktemp re2c
    squashfs-tools
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
   Suggested packages:
    gcc-multilib automake1.9 flex bison gcc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
         gcc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 67 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,098 B of archives.
After this operation, 42.0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main gcc amd64 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 [5,098 B]
Fetched 5,098 B in 0s (5,626 B/s)                      
Selecting previously unselected package gcc.
(Reading database ... 284177 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gcc_4%3a4.8.2-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gcc (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
```

You're done.